# java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi Deployed the following code in eclipse

```
//import cs1.Keyboard;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Parser
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String [][] addyArray = new String[50][4];
        for (int j=0; j<50; j++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k<4; k++)
            {
                addyArray[j][k] = "\n";
            }
        }
        FileReader inFile = new FileReader ("sample.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (inFile);
        String line = "";
        int i = 0, a = 0;
        while(in.ready())
        {
            line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null && line != "\n")
            {
                addyArray[i][a] = line;
                line = in.readLine();
                a++;
                if (line == null) line = "\n";
            }
            i++;
            a = 0;
        }
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
            {
                System.out.println((j+1) + "-" + (k+1) + " " + addyArray[j] [k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error at this line `FileReader inFile = new FileReader ("sample.txt");`

```
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Parser.main(Parser.java:19)
```

I placed sample.txt file in the same package folder where the above source code file was placed. I am not sure why I am getting this error. Can you please help me out. Thank you

Comment: What's the actual exception that you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a program in Eclipse, the current working directory, by default, is the root directory of your project. You probably have a sub-directory for your source code, so if you put "sample.txt" in it, it won't be found.

Either open the file as "<sub-directory>/sample.txt", or (preferably) move the file to the root of your Eclipse project.

Putting a file in your source code is only appropriate if it's a "resource"; that is, some information that doesn't need to be modified at runtime, but isn't convenient to express as Java source code. For example, localized text and images for a UI is a resource, while a  user-specified configuration for window sizes and positions is not. If a file is treated as a resource, you can load it with the [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method of `Class`.

Comment: Agreed.  getResourceAsStream() is my preferred method of grabbing resource-type files.

Answer (score 2):

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.txt")));
```

try this code, to read file, that located in the same directory

Answer (score 1):

It should be placed in resources folder

```
src/main/java  ... same package
src/main/resource ... same package
```